# How to make a class public only to another class

Tags: c++, oop

I have two separate distinct classes in C++, Node and Graph. I want to make the contents of Node accessible via the methods in graph but not public, how do I do this?

Comment: Friend is your friend? https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/friend

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a [`friend`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/friend) declaration to specify `class`es or functions that you'd like to give full access to the   `private` and `protected` members.

Example:

```
class Node {
    // ...
private:
    friend class Graph;
    int x;
};

class Graph {
public:
    void foo(Node& n) {
        n.x = 1; // wouldn't work without `friend` above
    }
};

int main() {
    Graph g;
    Node n;
    g.foo(n);
}
```

Comment: Tactical note: Sometimes, and very often when working with a graph problem, it's better to leave the node class entirely `public` and hide the node inside the graph class so that no one but the graph class can use it.

Comment: @user4581301 Agree. I didn't put any thought into why OP wants this. I think the comment is better under the actual question :-)

Comment: @user4581301 Something like this: https://godbolt.org/z/hxasadYKK

Comment: @rturrado That doesn't look like "_two separate distinct classes_". Again, suggestions regarding the design better go as comment to the OP who only left us with two names, `Node` and `Graph`.